# Weird scale on a graph

Tags: pgfplots

Given the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor,hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepackage{eurosym}      %<-- For EURO symbol 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usetheme{boxes}
\usecolortheme{default}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number] % To replace the footer line in all slides with a simple slide count uncomment this line

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % To remove the navigation symbols from the bottom of all slides uncomment this line
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\beamersetaveragebackground{white}


%\AtBeginSection[] % Do nothing for \section*
%{
%   \begin{frame}<beamer>
%       \frametitle{Outline}
%       \tableofcontents[currentsection]
%   \end{frame}
%}

\begin{filecontents*}{data2.csv}
    in gna  gnb gnc gnd gne gnf gng
1992    2074.59 9098.43   7297.28   4508.48 4601.50 6780.65 2173.23
1993    1912.62 9094.61  7263.52    4665.14 4207.40 6883.25 1863.03
1994    1690.82 9355.82  7487.83    4901.70 3683.10 7281.64 1442.90
1995    1519.88 9943.98   7609.95   5235.35 3529.55 7684.62 1276.92
1996    1567.67 10381.93    7626.33 5557.75 3407.44 8186.54 1159.47
1997    1753.80 10323.05    7903.44 5947.69 3460.86 8667.24 1134.98
1998    1910.19 10300.18    8255.34 6241.75 3282.86 9002.87 1123.41
1999    1981.83 10458.98    8547.34 6524.68 3503.79 8975.25 1131.78
2000    2103.06 10938.73    8931.84 6874.04 3870.41 9096.17 1210.69
2001    2219.52 11314.97    9296.94 6958.81 4084.78 9415.06 1335.43
2002    2346.39 11523.52    9741.22 7062.53 4298.28 9844.46 1418.90
2003    2529.08 11942.00    10144.68    7319.07 4632.85 10384.73    1564.92
2004    2838.06 12529.01    10669.19    7699.46 4985.33 10933.08    1767.64
2005    3126.37 13317.73    11155.96    7976.07 5323.47 11631.35    1828.72
2006    3460.13 14195.04    11598.64    8475.37 5776.40 12617.75    1975.53
2007    3775.00 14892.76    11666.09    9090.68 6280.15 13980.74    2144.35
2008    4174.02 15170.15    11784.63    9445.78 6612.63 14758.37    2205.58
2009    4191.61 14353.63    11028.74    9688.03 6093.63 13929.36    1887.52
2010    4524.16 14640.34    11135.84    10075.11    6365.21 14623.60    1974.62
2011    4783.53 14897.43    11363.71    10574.04    6631.46 15019.81    2084.78
2012    4870.98 14742.66    11229.63    10739.20    6845.77 15222.69    2094.12
2013    4922.24 14659.93    11473.40    10881.59    6922.80 15423.47    2098.89
2014    4998.28 14955.20    11932.61    11257.60    6843.92 15797.52    2081.06


\end{filecontents*}
\title{Eyyyynej}
\author{Anjjjjjk}
\date{16 marca 2016}

\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

            \begin{frame}{Wwwp}
                        \begin{adjustbox}{max totalsize={\textwidth}{0.9\textheight},center}
                            \begin{tikzpicture}
                            \centering
                            \begin{axis}[
                            width=\textwidth,
                            height=10cm,
                            ymajorgrids,
                            title = {Źródło: Opracoweeeedstawie Woqqwqwqpment Indicators},
                            x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
                            ytick scale label code/.code={},
                            legend pos=outer north east,
                            ylabel={PKB per capita (2005 US\$)}
                            ]
                            \addplot[mark=x, violet, very thick] table[x=in,y=gna] {data2.csv};\addlegendentry{Białoruś}
                            \addplot table[x=in,y=gnb] {data2.csv};\addlegendentry{Czechy}

                            \addplot table[x=in,y=gnc] {data2.csv};\addlegendentry{Węgry}
                            \addplot table[x=in,y=gnd] {data2.csv};\addlegendentry{Polska}
                            \addplot table[x=in,y=gne] {data2.csv};\addlegendentry{Rosja}
                            \addplot[green, very thick] table[x=in,y=gnf] {data2.csv};\addlegendentry{Słowacja}
                            \addplot[pink, very thick] table[x=in,y=gng] {data2.csv};\addlegendentry{Ukraina}
                            \end{axis}
                            \end{tikzpicture}

                        \end{adjustbox}
            \end{frame}

    \end{document}
```

In return i have a chart with strange y labels i mean i have data like two, three thousands whereas on y line ticks i have 0.8, 1.2 etc. how to fix that?

Comment: `scaled y ticks=false` should help. BTW do not load packages more than once.

Comment: Thanks, i didnt notice that with those packages, corrected :)

Comment: @esdd Would you like to convert you comment into an answer?